# Dynamically displaying Items using FlipView and DataTemplateSelector in WinRT

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, windows-runtime

I'm using Flipview and a DataTemplateSelector to determine at runtime which DataTemplate to apply to show items in my control.

I have two DataTemplate's, one is static and the second can be used by a undetermined number of items.

**Currently**

My first view displays:
- "This is a test - Content"

`Followed by 18 other views` that look like this:
- "http://www.google.com/ 0" 
- "http://www.google.com/ 1" 
- "http://www.google.com/ 2" 
- and so on until 17

**I want**

The items "http://www.google.com/ " to be grouped as `3 on a view`.

For example the second view will display:

- "http://www.google.com/ 0, http://www.google.com/ 1, http://www.google.com/ 2"

The third view will display:

- "http://www.google.com/ 3, http://www.google.com/ 4, http://www.google.com/ 5"

And so on..

Bellow is my code:

**FlipViewDemo.xaml**

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="FirstDataTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}" Margin="10,0,18,18"></TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SecondDataTemplate">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Url}"></TextBox>
    </DataTemplate>
    <local:MyDataTemplateSelector x:Key="MyDataTemplateSelector"
                FirstTextTemplate="{StaticResource FirstDataTemplate}"
                SecondTextTemplate="{StaticResource SecondDataTemplate}">
    </local:MyDataTemplateSelector>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <FlipView x:Name="itemGridView" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyDataTemplateSelector}" 
    Margin="265,220,284,162">
    </FlipView>
</Grid>
```

**FlipViewDemo.xaml.cs**

```
public sealed partial class FlipViewDemo : Page
{
    public FlipViewDemo()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        var items = new List<BaseClass>();

        items.Add(new FirstItem
        {
            Content="This is a test - Content"
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++)
        {
            items.Add(new SecondItem
            {
                Url = "http://www.google.com/ " + i.ToString() 
            });
        }
        itemGridView.ItemsSource = items;
    }
}
public class BaseClass
{
}

public class FirstItem : BaseClass
{
    public string Content { get; set; }
}

public class SecondItem : BaseClass
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
}

public class MyDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate FirstTextTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate SecondTextTemplate { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item,
                                                       DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item is FirstItem)
            return FirstTextTemplate;
        if (item is SecondItem)
            return SecondTextTemplate;

        return base.SelectTemplateCore(item, container);
    }
}
```

I'm thinking that maybe this can be achieved with groups and list view. But I'm not sure how this can be done.

Probably it is a stupid question but, using Google, I can't find an answer. Also english is not my native language; please excuse typing errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the way to achieve what you are looking for is to expose the data in a way that better represents what you want to display. Then, you can use nested controls to display it. I just threw this together (using my own test data). It is probably not exactly what you want, but it should help you figure things out.

**ViewModel**
Here I made a helper method to build the collection with sub-collections that each have 3 items.

```
class FlipViewDemo
{
    private List<object> mData;

    public IEnumerable<object> Data
    {
        get { return mData; }
    }

    public FlipViewDemo()
    {
        mData = new List<object>();
        mData.Add("Test String");
        for (int i = 0; i < 18; ++i)
        {
            AddData("Test Data " + i.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void AddData(object data)
    {
        List<object> current = mData.LastOrDefault() as List<object>;
        if (current == null || current.Count == 3)
        {
            current = new List<object>();
            mData.Add(current);
        }
        current.Add(data);
    }
}

class TemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate ListTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate ObjectTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item is List<object>) return ListTemplate;
        return ObjectTemplate;
    }
}
```

**Xaml**
Here I use an ItemsControl to vertically stack the items in the data. Each item is either a list of three objects or a single object. I use a `FlipView` for each of the lists of three objects and a simple `ContentPresenter` for the single objects.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ListTemplate">
        <FlipView
            ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentPresenter
                        Margin="0 0 10 0"
                        Content="{Binding}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
        </FlipView>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ObjectTemplate">
        <ContentPresenter
            Margin="0 0 10 0"
            Content="{Binding}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <local:TemplateSelector
        x:Key="TemplateSelector"
        ListTemplate="{StaticResource ListTemplate}"
        ObjectTemplate="{StaticResource ObjectTemplate}" />
</Page.Resources>

<ItemsControl
    ItemsSource="{Binding Data}"
    ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TemplateSelector}" />
```

Note: You usually would not need a template selector for something like this, but since you need to select between a `List<T>` and an `Object`, there is no way I know of to recognize the difference using only the `DataTemplate.TargetType` property from Xaml due to `List<t>` being a generic type. (I tried `` {x:Type collections:List`1} `` and it did not work.)

Comment: Hi Xavier, thank you very much. I tried to run this in the simulator, but didn't get anything just a black screen. Does this work for you?

Comment: It did work for me, but I set it up slightly different from your original setup. I made FlipViewDemo a separate class and set it as the data context on the view, rather than putting the code in the code-behind. Also, I ran it as a regular Windows WPF app rather than WinRT (because I am not setup for that). I only intended the code to be a reference, not a drop in and run example. I mainly wanted to highlight the areas that address your specific question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to group items in viewmodel, and databind ItemsSource to the groups. In flipview's itemtemplate you display items in group.

```
public class PageGroup : PageBase {
    public ObservableColection<BaseClass> Items { get; set; }
}

public ObservableCollection<PageBase> Pages { get; set; }
```

```
<FlipView ItemsSource="{Binding Pages}">
     <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate DataType="local:PageGroup">
             <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                           ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyDataTemplateSelector}" />
         </DataTemplate>
     </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
 </FlipView>
```

In order to display first page differently from others:

```
public class FirstPage : PageBase {
    public string Title { get; }
}

Pages.Insert(0, new FirstPage());
```

and you need to use another datatemplaeselector or impicit datatemplates in FlipView to differentiate between FirstPage and PageGroup

```
<FlipView ItemsSource="{Binding Pages}" 
          ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource PageTemplateSelector}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to worry about selecting the appropriate template based on the class type, you can simply define the class in the `DataTemplate` itself.

```
<DataTemplate TargetType="{x:Type myNamespace:FirstItem}">
   ...
</DataTemplate>
```

You'll need to specify where the class is by adding the namespace at the top of your page:

```
xmlns:myNamespace="clr-namespace:MyApp.MyNamespace"
```

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your answer.  I don't understand how this can help me display 3 items per view instead of 1

Comment: I believe he is just saying you can remove the template selector and update the data templates themselves to have a `TargetType` defined on them. That will simplify your existing code, but it does not answer your actual question.